# Add-in commands not visible for some users

Tags: outlook-web-addins

In 2017, I updated our Outlook add-in to use add-in commands instead of the now deprecated custom pane. Since then, all of our users have been using the new version without problems. However, recently at least 2 of our users are not able to see any of the add-in commands. They only see the deprecated custom pane button in the email read view. When they try open the custom pane, an error is shown:

[image]

This happens both on Outlook 2016 desktop (version 1807) and Outlook Web Access. Removing and re-installing the add-in through the office store (not side-loaded) does not seem to resolve the issue. Is it possible they are getting an outdated manifest file when the add-in is being installed?

Manifest file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gtDbO5NdiRyvTqSMcP04oeVvHXK8U7DQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you share the build number of Outlook 2016. Are they side loading the addin? Could you also share the manifest so we can try on our end too?

Comment: I tested your Manifest on recent builds of Outlook, and it seems to work fine. (so there is likely nothing wrong with your manifest). Going "backward" to the old version can happen if the Outlook version that they have is outdated. But you are only specifying API set 1.4. If they are on desktop outlook 16, 1807 it should support 1.4. The error that is showing up usually means that the computer cannot reach the add-in (https://outlook.insightly.com/Home), which is curious.

Comment: If the add-in was installed by admins, it can take some time before the update reaches all end users. (but if from the store, it should happen almost immediately if not on reboot). 

Given this information, I could be possible that the user cannot reach the Exchange server to download the latest manifest, and is loading the old manifest from cache? You can check the Desktop Outlook cache at: C:\Users\\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\\[some guid]\\[some string]\Manifests\\[add-in id guid]

Comment: Then check the update time on the file, and the contents of the manifest.

Comment: Just to clarify what does "Office 365 online" mean? Is that the desktop client or Outlook Web Access?

Comment: Thanks for editing the post to clarify "Office 365 online". Do you have access to the 2 users who are hitting this problem? Are you able to access their machines to check for the manifest in the local cache path?